# how to get dirname of a GFile?

Tags: python, gio, dirname

When using GIO and GVFS, how do I best get the directory name of a GFile object? There is a get_basename() function but no get_dirname().

The function should work for remote URIs as well. Also, it should be available in Python.

Answer (score 2):

First get the `GFile` for the dir, then get the name of the dir:

```
GFile* dir = g_file_get_parent(gfile));
char* dir_name = g_file_get_parse_name(dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html. There is a dirname function which might help. Dont know if it will work for remote URIs as well. Just try it out.